# How to return random generated name instead of ID when starting docker container

Tags: docker, shell

Running docker containers in detached mode (`docker run -d foo`) returns the container id (long version). But can it return the (random generated) container name? Since the [command reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) does not indicates such a functionality, I tried using `xargs` to pipe  the returned id into a `docker ps` command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 container-name | xargs -I % docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' --filter id=%
```

This does not work because either the id is not really returned but only printed by docker run or because I do not use xargs correctly.

Comment: `But that does not seem to work` <= [this does not accurately describe your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: null byte problem => `... | xargs -0 -I % docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' --filter id=%`. Note that since you launch a single container, using a subshell might be a bit more straightforward: `docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' --filter id=$(docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image-name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 container-name | \
  xargs docker container inspect -f '{{ slice .Name 1 }}'
```

This uses `docker container inspect` instead of `docker ps` because you already know exactly which container you want to query. The name of the container is under the `.Name` field, but it has a leading `/` that I strip off with `slice .Name 1` which is the same as `Name[1:]` in Go.